# Хранение файлов на стороне MS SQL сервера

Tags: c#, sql-server

Имеется бумажный архив документов и диаграмм по различным исследованиям.
На удаленном компьютере стоит MS SQL 2014 Express.
**Цель:** создать БД с описанием архива документов для дальнейшего анализа содержимого архива. При сканировании документа/диаграммы сохранить ссылку на него в БД.
 Где хранить отсканированный файл, так что-бы к нему был доступ с любого другого компьютера в сети/интернете?

**P.S.:** Файлы очень довольно большие. 35.000 файлов, объемом 100 Гб. Думаю хранить такие объемы в базе просто не целесообразно

Comment: filestream, например?

Comment: БД не хранит файлы. "Место" для хранения данных называется в базах blob - поле.   С ним разные клиенты (С++,C#,php) по-разному работают. Конкретно в MSSQL есть blob, xml (для файлов xml), ну и можно использовать на крайний случай varchar(8000) около 7 кb текста. Есть другие типы, но они производные от blob  binary  varbinary image https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms187752%28v=sql.120%29.aspx

Comment: Что б организовать доступ к "файлу" нужно написать "шлюз" который будет записывать/забирать данные из blob поля. А ключ доступа - как ваша фантазия позволяет, от id до имени пути.

Comment: Есть и недостаток, при хранении файлов в СУБД MSSQL у вас есть ограничение на 4GB (Enterprise) и на 10-20 GB. Когда внутри СУБД закончится место - база перестанет работать. Поэтому на вашем 2014 EE есть 4GB на 1 базу (за минусом места под служебную информацию)

Comment: для чего Вам нужна *бд с описанием и структуризацией архива файлов.*, т.е. для чего Вы хотите её в дальнейшем использовать? как попадают файлы в *архив*?

Comment: У нас есть диаграммы на бумажном носители. Их сканируют по мере необходимости и запросу и этот скан образ сохраняют в файловое хранилище. Каждая диаграмма это часть какого-то исследования (т.е. по одному исследованию несколько диаграмм в разных частях). Сейчас встал вопрос: Какова изученность исследованиями? Каково состояние перевода (оцифровки) архива? Что еще необходимо сканировать? В итоге, все бумажные носители должны быть отсканированы и оцифрованны.

Comment: @Bald Немного изменил вопрос

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для хранения файлов на стороне SQL Server существует механизм [Filestream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716724(v=vs.110).aspx). Это механизм хранит BLOB-ы (файлы) не в самой базе, а в отдельной папке, что предотвращает разрастание БД.

Filestream поддерживается на SQL Express, но может быть выключен по умолчанию. Включается в свойствах базы через Management Studio, или напряму через SQL.

Для доступа к нему со стороны C# есть класс [`SqlFileStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqlfilestream(v=vs.110).aspx).

Альтернатива - просто вручную складывать файлы в общую папку на сервере + хранить в базе пути к файла.

Comment: Если использовать `SqlFileStream` файлы которые я сохраню в базе потом просто так не вытащить? Т.е. это уже не будет "1.jpg"?

Comment: Это будет отдельно лежащий файл, но с именем-guid-ом

Comment: @MaximK да, файлы будут как бы в общей "куче", зачастую без расширений и открыть их без БД будет сложнее. Вот пример настройки - http://kooboo-cms.ru/articles/detail/enable-filestream-on-exist-database-by-interface-sql-server-management-studio/ Однако может быть удобнее (как я сама иногда делаю), писать мини-приложение для складывания файлов в определенную директорию (можно в файловую шару), с ручным созданием связи файла с записью в БД.